# Multiple folders in one docker volume

Tags: docker, volume

I have two folders, let's say /etc/folder1 and /etc/folder2. I want to map them both in the same docker volume. So that I have these two folders in the root of my volume. Is that possible?

What I want is:

```
/etc/folder1 
/etc/folder2
and then /vol1/folder1 and /vol1/folder2
```

Comment: do you use docker-compose or just Dockerfile?

Comment: Using docker-compose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think it is possible with:

```
php:
    image: imagename
    volumes:
        -/etc/folder1:/folder1
        -/etc/folder2:/folder2
```

you have to create folder1 & folder2 in your Dockerfile.

```
...
RUN  mkdir folder1 folder2
...
```

Comment: I will try and letting you know afterwards. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: its the right way localfolder:dockerfolder. did you create all the folders on your local system and in your docker-container?

Comment: Nope, it's the other way round. I already edited your answer, but it has to be reviewed. I tried it the right way. Has to be volume:localfolder

Comment: okay. in my docker-compose its the way i wrote it^^. i mount:  '- ./www:/var/www/'. a local www into the docker-container /var/www/

Comment: Thank you! Marked your solution.

Answer (score 5):

Yes:

```
> mkdir ~/vol1
> mkdir ~/vol2
> touch ~/vol1/file1
> touch ~/vol2/file2
> docker run -it -v ~/vol1:/vol1 -v ~/vol2:/vol2 ubuntu find / -name file*
/vol2/file2
/vol1/file1
...
```

You can mount multiple volumes into a container, and you can event mount individual files from the host into the container using volumes.